# How to sync a data from windows app to cloud within wine?

Tags: ubuntu-one, wine, sync, cloud, dropbox

I am using xin inventory which is a very nice inventory management windows application. I bought it a couple of years back and I use it to manage around 600 products. Xin Inventory is only thing which is stopping me from completely migrating to linux.

Now in ubuntu I know I can use the app with the help of wine but is there any way within wine by which I can sync xin inventory data over cloud. On windows I simply installed xin inventory in dropbox folder and that let me access the data from all my computers, which is pretty convenient. I wanted same in ubuntu.

Kindly suggest me the best possible way of achieving this.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1):

If you have no problems running xin under wine but you want to synchronize other folders outside the wine installation, you could try with a symbolic link:

```
ln -s $HOME/Dropbox /path/to/.wine/folder
```

I use something similar to synchronize saved games between computers under Wine.

Comment: Will that sync all the folders within wine to dropbox?

Comment: That will create a link to a wine folder of your choice inside dropbox.